# urllib3 and requests, fix status code 403 in urllib3, requests work good as well

Tags: python, python-requests, proxy, authorization, urllib3

When I run the code only requests code work and it's return status code `200`. and urllib3 fail, it return status code `403`. I want urllib3 will return the same as requests results, here are the following codes:

requests code:

```py
import requests

proxies = {"http":"http://username:password@host:port"} #proxy protocol


r = requests.get('https://www.examples.com', proxies=proxies) #make the request

print(r.status_code) #return status code 200, successful request
```

urllib3 code:

```py
import urllib3

auth_headers = urllib3.make_headers(proxy_basic_auth='username:password') #proxy authorization build

Proxy = urllib3.ProxyManager(proxy_url="http://host:port", proxy_headers=auth_headers)

url = 'https://www.example.com/'

r = Proxy.request('GET', url) #make the request

print(r.status) #return status code 403, I want it to return status code 200 like the same as the requests code.
```

Edited: It's also work good with PoolManager()

Comment: Please join the issue and help!

Comment: use the following `{"https": "http://username:password@host:port"}` and apply the same for `http`

Comment: @αԋɱҽԃαмєяιcαη The request api doesn't support `https`, It's support only `http`

Comment: I just want the urllib3 code will return the same results as requests code

Comment: https://requests.readthedocs.io/en/latest/user/advanced/#proxies